# How to insert markdown into a React component with MDX

Tags: reactjs, mdxjs

If I have some stuff in a markdown file `foo.md`, what is the best way to "inject" this into a component `<Bar />`? I'm assuming I will have to use some props right? Or is MDX not suitable for this type of problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think I've figured it out -- you can just directly import it like `import Content from "./foo.mdx"`, you just need to configure some files correctly so the imports work (I was using nextjs and in `next-env.d.ts` I needed to add `declare module '*.mdx'`). Still curious if there are other ideas though.